# How to write the sampler stats in jsr 223 sampler to a jmeter listener

Tags: apache, jmeter

I have a jsr223 sampler that does the following
1.load a external Java class
2.send some properties to class
3.java class would calculate and come up with resp time ,resp status 
4.jsr 223 sampler would receive the stats and need to show it in a listener
I'm using Sample Result.setsamplelabel and Sample result.setresponsecode("passed")
But how do I set the response time ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in the JSR223 Sampler itself, however you can amend parent sampler [Elapsed Time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the sampler which response time you want to change
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.writeField(prev, "elapsedTime", XXXX, true);
   ```

   Change `XXXX` to the desired response time (in milliseconds)
3. That's it, the Sampler's Elapsed Time now should have `XXXX` value

References:

- [Getting and Setting Field Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html)
- [Java Code Examples for org.apache.commons.lang.reflect.FieldUtils](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.commons.lang.reflect.FieldUtils)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)