# How to customize Jmeter sample time?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am using Jmeter 5.1 for my application API performance test. As per my business logic, I should not take sample time from Jmeter. Instead , I need to take elapsed time which is available in response body and Pass it to Jmeter for sample Time then I can use JMeter sample time. How to customize Jmeter sample time ?.

OR

How to add my response's elapsedTime in summary / Aggregate reports ?

My response payload:

```
{
"a": "res1",
"b":"res2",
"elapsedTime":"25"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns the above response
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   import groovy.json.*;

   def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
   def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response);
   def elapsedTime = json.elapsedTime as Long;
   org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.writeField(prev, "elapsedTime", elapsedTime, true);
3. You can see response’s elapsedTime reflection in all reports.

Thanks @Dimitri , I referred your response [How to write the sampler stats in jsr 223 sampler to a jmeter listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932681/how-to-write-the-sampler-stats-in-jsr-223-sampler-to-a-jmeter-listener)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite JMeter's internal metric with the value from the response as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above response
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   prev.elapsedTime = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).elapsedTime as Long
   ```
3. That's it, the parent Sampler elapsed time will change to the one from the response

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: @Dimitri Thanks for response. I have followed step 1 & 2. But I don't see my elapsed time in Result in Table's Sample Time.  Please help me.

Comment: Really? Here is the evidence of the approach working:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Hmo.gif. If it doesn't work for you - check [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for any suspicious entries.

Comment: Thanks I found the answer by referring your response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932681/how-to-write-the-sampler-stats-in-jsr-223-sampler-to-a-jmeter-listener